# Solve the factorial equation $x! = c$

Tags: factorial

How to find the value of $x$ which its factorial for example equals to 100 ?

$x! = 100 $

$x= ?$

Comment: $4! = 24$ and $5! = 120$, so there is no such x in integers.

Comment: 4.89252 has $\Gamma(x+1) \simeq 100$.

Comment: Factoriel is an increasing function in itegers. where isnot clear that you asked shailesh to prove it for you?

Comment: From the way OP asked the question, I did not want to get into gamma functions. It looked like a simple question and deserved an squally simple answer

Comment: To prove it's enough observing that $n!$ is strictly increasing for $n \ge 1$, then use @Shailesh 's observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such integer. If you generalize to reals with Gamma function, $x!\to\Gamma(x+1)$, then you have an ugly transcendental equation which you need to attack numerically, no way around it. Bisection is probably the safest bet.

If it happens to be integer, I'd do a linear search... just increase $x$ in $x!$ until you get to the solution. If you jump *over* it, then there's no integer solution and you have a bracket for the continuous case with the Gamma function.

Comment: what if the number is so large, what we will do in this case ?!

Comment: @Reem Well... how big the number is doesn't really matter, unless you are worried about numerical solving with a computer with single or double precision... but $x!$ is the one that is large, not $x$. So if you can actually represent your input value with a valid number, then solving for $x$ will not be a problem. With bisection, you will get the $52$ bits of precision (double precision) in $52$ iterations - not too bad.

Otherwise, because the Gamma function is so fast growing, $\log \Gamma(x)$ is frequently implemented as a function, so you can use that to solve the equation.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to solving this would be bisection in my opinion, and it goes as follows:$$4!<100<5!$$$$4.5!<100<5!$$$$4.75!<100<5!$$$$4.875!<100<5!$$$$4.875!<100<4.9!$$$$4.89!<100<4.9!$$$$x\approx4.895$$Bisection works great as long as the function is **only growing or decaying** in the area which we are considering.

You start with two guesses and get closer by a half each time, hence bisection.

And it doesn't half to get closer by exactly a half each time (the decimals get longer if you do so), which is why you may have noticed that I went from $4.875$ to $4.9$.