# Yet another request for how to do the Inverse (Gamma(x-1) Function -- involves Lambert W

Tags: factorial, gamma-function, lambert-w

I have looked far and wide here and at other math forums for how to compute the Inverse of the Gamma Function as it relates to Factorials, ie: getting x from x!

So far, these two links seems to be to hold the most promise for what I'm looking for:
[Inverse of a factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078997/inverse-of-a-factorial)
and David Cantrell's posting:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171104030158/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=342551&tstart=0)

robjohn and Claude Leibovici posted good explanations as to what Cantrell was trying to say.

$$
n=[e^{W(log[n!/√{2π}]/e)+1}−1/2]
$$

However, I'm running into the problem in that I CAN'T figure out how to solve the portion of the formula that involves the Lambert W Function!

I can get up to this point: $s=(log[n!/√{2π}]/e)$, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to proceed with $n=[e^{W(s)+1}−1/2]$. And unfortunately, the Wikipedia article for the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is sorely lacking on how to actually apply it to solving problems involving it.
Can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a video by BlackRedPen on youtube talking about the W Lambert: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWgNCra93D8 where he’s telling us how to solve for **$x^x=2$**. I still don’t have a math proof to answer my question on how to use Lambert W for Cantrell’s work, but BlackRedPen does finish off his lecture with the answer in the form of **$x=e^{W(ln2)}$**… then he points the audience to Wolfram’s “Productlog” function! 
Plugging in what I worked Cantrell’s formula out to be above, I get:

In terms of **Γ(x)**, it shows up as: **$[e^{W(log[n!/√{2π}]/e)+1}−1/2]$**, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5E%28productlog%28%28ln%5Bn%21%2F%E2%88%9A%282%CF%80%29%5D%2Fe%29%29%2B1%29%29%2B1%2F2);

if you want in terms of **n!**, change the formula to **$[e^{W(log[n!/√{2π}]/e)+1}+1/2]$**, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5E%28productlog%28%28ln%5Bn%21%2F%E2%88%9A%282%CF%80%29%5D%2Fe%29%29%2B1%29%29-1%2F2)

which works out pretty close when using Windows Calc.exe.

I hope that helps anyone else who might be beating their head against the wall as I have had. And if anyone has an elegant expression that answers my previous post, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Hi emonHR, Thanks for the edits! That's a much better appearance. I'm still rather new with what tools are available to us here.