# unequal factorial equation

Tags: factorial

I need to solve the equation $(n+1)! \geq 2~\cdot 10^{10}$ for $n$, without filling in $n$ every single time. How can I get rid of $n$ in the factorial (or just the factorial as a whole) so I can seclude $n$?

Comment: Use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation_)?  Or just trial and error.

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2079043), it is shown that
$$
n\sim e\exp\left(\operatorname{W}\left(\frac1{e}\log\left(\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)\right)\right)-\frac12
$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse of a factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078997)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no doubt that the solution proposed by robjohn is beautifule, elegant, efficient and so on !

If you want a shortcut method, what you could use (based on a quick and dirty nonlinear regression) is
$$\log[(x+1)!]=a+b\, x^c+d\, x^{2c}$$

Using values for $0 \leq x \leq 200$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +4.24333  & 0.135964 & \{+3.97518,+4.51148\} \\
 b & -4.14423 & 0.058518  & \{-4.25964,-4.02882\} \\
 c & +0.58454  & 0.000361 & \{+0.58383,+0.58525\} \\
 d & +1.95215  & 0.009428 & \{+1.93356,+1.97075\} \\
\end{array}$$

which leaves you with a quadratic equation in $x^c$.

Applied to your case, this would give $$x^c=4.3936\implies x=12.5807$$ which is the order of magnitude (but easy to get). However, $13.5807!\approx 2.85804\times 10^{10}$ which is a bit too high.

But you can polish the solution using Stirling approximation
$$\log[(x+1)!]=x (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+3 \log
   \left({x}\right)\right)+\frac{13}{12 x}-\frac{1}{2
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$ and use one or two iterations of Newton method to the equation

$$f(x)=x (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+3 \log
   \left({x}\right)\right)+\frac{13}{12 x}-\frac{1}{2
   x^2}-\log(a)$$
$$f'(x)=\log (x)+\frac{3}{2 x}-\frac{13}{12 x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}$$ For your case, a single iteration would give $x=12.4458$ and we can check that $13.4458!\approx 2.00162 \times 10^{10}$.