# How to find the nearest factorial to a number

Tags: factorial

How can I find the nearest Factorial to a number? For example I know that the nearest factorial to `200` is `5!` So how can I also find out the nearest factorial to another number `2864785456`?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse of a factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078997/inverse-of-a-factorial).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3097092/589

Comment: I would suggest to solve $$\Gamma(x+1)=n$$ numerically and correctly round.