# How do you solve the equation x!=n, for any value of n?

Tags: factorial

About 5 years ago, I did some research into factorials. I came across a problem online that asked me to solve x!=6. The answer was 3, of course, but when I tried to solve x!=3, I found no value of x that would work. It is a decimal, because I set the gamma function equal to three. I need assistance in solving the gamma part.

Comment: I was under the impression that Sterling's approximation to N-Factorial would do the trick, but maybe you mean something else. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224592/inverse-of-the-gamma-function#comment6636192_3224592 . This is a very good approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a language or system that has both gamma function for all real values and a root solver. 
Then find a root of $\Gamma(x) - n=0
$.

The Lanczos approximation
(see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation)
can,
combined with the reflection formula,
allow the computation of the Gamma function
at all points in the complex plane
where it is defined.

I have done this in the past
using HP calculators.
By using an Aitken iteration,
I was able to get results for
complex $n$ as well as real.

It was fun finding $x$
for complex $n$.

Looking up "inverse factorial"
gives interesting links
like this:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01734

Have fun.