# What number's factorial is $i$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function

I am trying to find the solution to the equation- $$\Gamma(z)=i$$
I have tried doing it the following way- LHS is-
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}t^ze^{-t}\ dt$$
Taking $z=a+ib$, we get-
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{a+ib}e^{-t}\ dt$$
or
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{a}t^{ib}e^{-t}\ dt$$
Using Euler's formula- $e^{i\theta}=\text{cos}\ \theta +\ i\ \text{sin}\ \theta$, we have-
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{a}(\text{cos}\ (b\ \text{ln}t)  +\ i\ \text{sin}\ (b\ \text{ln}t)) e^{-t}\ dt$$
After this point, I am not being able to solve this integral. I have tried graphing it on desmos, but it doesn't seem like this question has any solution. How can I approach further in this?

Comment: In india we call $i$ as iota? Is that wrong?

Comment: If you want numerical solutions you can plug it in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma%28x%29%3Di)

Comment: Or inverting Gamma, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224592/inverse-of-the-gamma-function).

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar Iota is a Greek letter along with pi, alpha, beta etc.  It is the ancestor of the Latin / English I in the same way that alpha is the ancestor of A.  In its upper case form it looks just like I but again that is similar to alpha whose upper case looks like A.  The local case of iota $\iota$ looks a little different in that it lacks the dot.  It is not very often used in maths but, if it was, it would be regarded as a distinct symbol.

Comment: I guess the point is that, US non-engineering they write $i$ for $\sqrt{-1}$.  In (some) engineering they write $j$.  And some places (India I guess) they write $\iota$.  So should we "correct" $\iota$ to $i$ on math.se?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the zero of function
$$f(z)=\Gamma(z)-i$$ I used Newton method with (why not ?) $z_0=1+i$. The iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & z_n\\
 0 & 1.00000+1.00000\,i \\
 1 & 2.56016+2.59498\,i\\
 2 & 2.24930+1.16218\,i \\
 3 & 2.72561+2.04341 \,i \\
 4 & 2.78276+1.60761\,i \\
 5 & 2.84247+1.68952\,i  \\
 6 & 2.84550+1.68427 \,i \\
 7 & 2.84550+1.68429 \,i 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using @Robjohn's approximation, we should obtain
$$z\sim e^{1+W(t)}+\frac 12\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac 1 e \log \left(\frac{i}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\right)$$ which, numerically, is $2.84071 +1.69496\, i$

Using it as $z_0$, Newton iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & z_n \\
 0 & 2.84071+1.69496\, i \\
 1 & 2.84547+1.68422\, i \\
 2 & 2.84550+1.68429\, i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Take care : this is only **one** of the many possible solutions (as usual when dealing with complex numbers).

**Warning :** In the previous edit of this answer, I had a terrible numerical mistake using @robjohn's superb approximation.

Comment: I'm sorry what's the Robjohn's approximation?

Comment: @SarthakGirdhar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078997/inverse-of-a-factorial/2079043#2079043

Comment: I found some root and plotted on the plane. Interesting https://imgur.com/WejKgwm

Comment: @Raffaele. I already mae it but thanks. If you want fun, make contour plots of the norm for $z=a+i b$