# Approximate solution of $\Gamma(z)=n\,i$

Tags: complex-numbers, approximation, gamma-function, lambert-w

*This is not a question but I hope and wish that it will not be deleted too fast.*

Today, I received an upvote for my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696715/what-numbers-factorial-is-i/3696746#3696746). Not remembering what the problem was (age, for sure !), I had a look at it and I was surprised to see that the superb approximation @robjohn made answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k/2078194#2078194) of mine (four years ago) was giving a rather poor estimate of one of the solutions of equation $\color{red}{\Gamma(z)=i}$.

Redoing my calculations, I found a terrible numerical mistake.

As a tribute to @robjohn (hoping that he will forgive me), I report here the solution obtained for
$$\color{red}{\Gamma(z)=n\,i}$$ for which the estimate is given by
$$\color{blue}{z\sim e^{1+W(t)}+\frac 12}\qquad \text{where} \qquad \color{blue}{t=\frac 1 e \log \left(\frac{n\,i}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\right)}$$  $W(t)$ being Lambert function.

Some impressive results

| $n$ | Approximation | Solution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $2.84071 +1.69496 \,i$ | $2.84550 +1.68429 \,i$ |
| $2$ | $3.34357 +1.44741 \,i$ | $3.35044 +1.43963 \,i$ |
| $3$ | $3.64315 +1.33808 \,i$ | $3.65025 +1.33195 \,i$ |
| $4$ | $3.85317 +1.27397 \,i$ | $3.86019 +1.26882 \,i$ |
| $5$ | $4.01366 +1.23065 \,i$ | $4.02051 +1.22614 \,i$ |
| $6$ | $4.14297 +1.19882 \,i$ | $4.14966 +1.19475 \,i$ |
| $7$ | $4.25095 +1.17409 \,i$ | $4.25749 +1.17037 \,i$ |
| $8$ | $4.34346 +1.15414 \,i$ | $4.34987 +1.15068 \,i$ |
| $9$ | $4.42428 +1.13756 \,i$ | $4.43056 +1.13432 \,i$ |
| $10$ | $4.49595 +1.12348 \,i$ | $4.50212 +1.12041 \,i$ |
| $20$ | $4.95332 +1.04533 \,i$ | $4.95880 +1.04314 \,i$ |
| $30$ | $5.21027 +1.00868 \,i$ | $5.21539 +1.00685 \,i$ |
| $40$ | $5.38829 +0.98573 \,i$ | $5.39318 +0.98411 \,i$ |
| $50$ | $5.52410 +0.96940 \,i$ | $5.52881 +0.96791 \,i$ |
| $60$ | $5.63366 +0.95690 \,i$ | $5.63824 +0.95551 \,i$ |
| $70$ | $5.72535 +0.94687 \,i$ | $5.72982 +0.94556 \,i$ |
| $80$ | $5.80411 +0.93855 \,i$ | $5.80849 +0.93730 \,i$ |
| $90$ | $5.87307 +0.93147 \,i$ | $5.87738 +0.93027 \,i$ |
| $100$ | $5.93438 +0.92534 \,i$ | $5.93862 +0.92418 \,i$ |
| $200$ | $6.32917 +0.88910 \,i$ | $6.33302 +0.88818 \,i$ |
| $300$ | $6.55383 +0.87067 \,i$ | $6.55748 +0.86985 \,i$ |
| $400$ | $6.71067 +0.85862 \,i$ | $6.71420 +0.85787 \,i$ |
| $500$ | $6.83097 +0.84980 \,i$ | $6.83439 +0.84908 \,i$ |
| $600$ | $6.92840 +0.84289 \,i$ | $6.93176 +0.84222 \,i$ |
| $700$ | $7.01021 +0.83726 \,i$ | $7.01351 +0.83661 \,i$ |
| $800$ | $7.08066 +0.83252 \,i$ | $7.08391 +0.83189 \,i$ |
| $900$ | $7.14249 +0.82845 \,i$ | $7.14570 +0.827838 \,i$ |
| $1000$ | $7.19756 +0.82489 \,i$ | $7.20073 +0.824289 \,i$ |

Comment: Hi, the [Markdown syntax for tables](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32850/290189) has recently been available on the whole SE network.  I suggest using that as that's semantically more correct.

Comment: Wow how could you? Voted to close, downvoted, flagged user account for deletion for trying to add to the lexicon of math. :P

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會. Do you mind to edit in order I "see" how to make it. Being blind, it is difficult for me to adapt myself quickly. Thanks :-)

Comment: I'll edit it for you @ClaudeLeibovici :)

Comment: While I'm doing the job, I see @CameronWilliams's comment.  I'll see how his edit goes.

Comment: @CameronWilliams. I am sorry but I do not understand if your comment is positive, negative, ironic ... My English is very far to be good. Thanks for answereing :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It was in jest. I edited your post. Go ahead and take a "look" so you can see how it goes. If you're familiar with reddit table formatting, it's *very* similar.

Comment: @CameronWilliams. Do you like it ?   In any manner thank you.

Comment: It's pretty interesting! A very good approximation despite the simplicity.

Comment: I suggest using any text/code editor with multi-cursor support (like Sublime Text, Atom, Visual Studio Code) and/or regular expression support (like Vim, Emacs, and the previous editors mentioned) to do the tedious editing in the future.

Comment: @CameronWilliams. Search for *@ robjohn approximation my_name*. You could be really amazed.

Comment: I seize this chance to mention the possibility of text alignment within any particular column.  For example, $n$ varies from $1$ to $1000$, and the corresponding column can be left-aligned so that the units digit are aligned together as presenting in [my recently edited meta sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/10586/201).

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會. My wife and I love calligraphy. I printed the last part of your username and we admire every single day. It so beautiful (for several reasons). Thanks, my friend (hoping I may). Cheers and take care :-)

Comment: Of course my friend.  Cheers.  I'm glad to know that your wife and you love my user name.