# Constructing inequalities using approximations without fudging it in the direction I want to go in?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, approximation

[image]

I managed to solve this question but I did it in a way that just isn't good enough. I think the most sensible way to approach the calculation of $I_{n+1}$ is to evaluate the signs of $f(a_n), f(b_n), f(c_n)$, eg for $I_1$ I calculated $a_0 = \frac{\pi}{2} > 0$, $b_0 = \pi > 0$ and $c_0 = \frac{3\pi}{4}$, setting $f(c_0) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{3\pi}{4}<0$, $f(a_0) = 2 - \frac{\pi}{2} > 0$, $f(b_0) = -\pi < 0$ setting $I_1 = [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{4}]$.

These inequalities seem obvious to me. For  $f(c_0) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{3\pi}{4}<0$, this is obvious to me since $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} < 2$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4} > \frac{9}{4} > 2$. But this logic isn't extendable in the later parts of the question.

Later I needed to calculate $I_2$ and had the equation for $f(c_0)$ as $f(c_0) = 2\sin{(\frac{5\pi}{8}}) - \frac{5\pi}{8}$. Now I need to determine whether this is greater than or less than zero to zero in order to determine what $I_{n+1}$ should be.

I didn't know how to do this using the given approximations and everything I tried was too hand-wavey and stupid. I ended up having to make educated guesses (I was able to tell it was less than zero, and I also managed to get $I_3$ correct with educated guesswork).

How can I provide a solid argument to show whether expressions like these are greater than or less than zero?

A calculator is not allowed in this question.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: Sorry. The question can be found on this site by typing in '04-S2-Q7' as the search term: https://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/index.html# @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會

Comment: STEP questions have solutions on PMT. As a hint, you should use double angle formulas. https://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Maths/STEP/Solutions-and-Reports/2004%20Hints%20and%20Answers.pdf

Comment: Thx for providing us the source of your question.  However, [some visually impaired users](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949816/approximate-solution-of-gammaz-n-i#comment8144530_3949816) can't view images on this site.  Please don't hinder them from reading (or answering) your question.