# Whats wrong with my probability equations for these probability question?

Tags: probability

Johns wants to walk his dog on most mornings. If the weather is pleasant,(let $W$ denote walk the dog)  $P(W)=\frac{3}{4}$. If the weather is not pleasant, $P(W) = \frac{1}{3}$. For the month of January, (let $P$ denote pleasant weather) $P(P)= \frac{5}{8}$

So you could do this via tree diagram, two-way table, or probability equations. (I am having trouble manipulating the probability equations so I am trying to force myself to use them, although I'm having trouble understanding how to use them)

**Using a table:**

|  | W | W' |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P | 30 |  |  |
| P' | 9 |  |  |
|  | 39 | 33 | 72 |

Numers come from: $P(W|P)=\frac{3}{4}\frac{5}{8} =\frac{15}{32}$

Similarly $P(W|P')=\frac{1}{8}$

$LCM(8,32) = 72$ so let that be the imaginary sample space.

Therefore $P(W)=\frac{39}{71}$ which is incorrect.

**Using the probability equations**

$P(W\cap P)=\frac{3}{4}\frac{5}{8} =\frac{15}{32}$

Similarly $P(W\cap P')=\frac{1}{8}$

(And I am already confused: $P(W\cap P) = P(W|P$)? well from the table both seem right as in $W$ AND $P$ is the same as $W$ GIVEN $P$)

Then for $P(W) = \frac{P(W\cap P)}{P(P)} = \frac{\frac{15}{32}}{\frac{5}{8}}=\frac{3}{4}$ which again is wrong

What if I try $P\left(W\right)=P\left(W \cap\ P\right)+P\left(W\cap\ P'\right)$?

Nope.

**EDIT:** yes!! the last thing I wrote does give the correct solution $\frac{19}{32}$ ! Props to me. What about that table though?

Comment: Just as a general point:  you should never use a single notation to represent two distinct things.  Here, for instance, you start out writing $P(W)=\frac 34$ and $P(W)=\frac 13$.

Comment: LCM (8,32) =72?

Comment: Nor can I make any sense out of your table or your calculations.  The initial information you were given was conditional.  Thus you should have had $P(W\,|\,P)=\frac 34$ and $P(W\,|\,P^c)=\frac 13$.  Note:  I am not a fan of writing $P$ to mean both "probability" and "pleasant".  I think that working on your notation will help you avoid confusion.

Comment: Yeah ok I agree that my notation needs some serious improvement. My teachers actually say that often... I'm not sure of the best way to improve it though. I think Forester found the error in my table - I'll try it again with the new sample space

Comment: Concerning notation also avoid things like $P(P)$. E.g. take an $N$ for pleasant (=nice) weather.

Comment: @Forester Yeah!! I got the answer using the table as well. Thanks

Comment: @user71207 You are welcome :)

Comment: Follow up question: Is  $()=(∩ )+(∩ ′)$ for use in independent, dependent events or both?

Comment: Also could someone still explain why $P(P|W)$ and $P(P\cap W)$ BOTH make (or perhaps do not make sense if I am wrong) sense when considering the table?

Answer (score 2):

Very easy solution. I considered the 31 days of January in the bottom of the table.

The pleasant days are $\frac{5}{8}\cdot 31\approx 19$. Thus the unpleasant days are 12.

If the day is pleasant I walk with probability 0.75, thus in the cell $(P,W)=19\cdot 0.75\approx14$ and so on....

this is the resulting table

|  | Walk | Do not Walk | Total days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Pleasant** | 14 | 5 | 19 |
| **Not Pleasant** | 4 | 8 | 12 |
| **Total days** | **18** | **13** | **31** |

It is evident that $P(W)=\frac{18}{31}$

If this result is not the same of the one you are expecting to find, do not approximate like i did...but the procedure should be understood.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, I actually messed up the month - it should be "April". However, does the number of days actually matter? I suppose it is possible to find a solution simply using the sample space of the number of days in the given month. Thanks anyway

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 : sorry guy....I'm working at it was only a way to save time...if it does disturb you I can cancel the post

Comment: @tommik Markdown tables are easy to write: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/259305

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 : amended....as I told you, it was just a way to save time...

Comment: @tommik We have some [high-rep users](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949816/approximate-solution-of-gammaz-n-i#comment8144530_3949816) who can't see text images. Please don't hinder them from viewing your tables.