# Improving bounds on n, where n is the least integer such that n!>k^k for positive integer k

Tags: factorial, analytic-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I was looking at the ratio
$$\frac{k!}{k^k} =\frac{1*2*3*...*k}{k*k*k*...*k}<1$$
and I wondered how large of a factorial I would need to make the ratio greater than one.
So,
$$\frac{n!}{k^k} =\frac{1*2*3*...*k*...*n}{k*k*k*...*k}>1$$
I have found that since $$\frac{(2k)!}{k^k}=\frac{1*2*3*...*k*...*2k}{k*k*k*...*k}$$the right half of the factors in the numerator are all greater than $k$, and we have that ${(2k)!}>{k^k}$.

Therefore, n is bounded by $$k<n<2k.$$
I have attempted to improve these bounds but have not been able to make progress.$$$$
I started with the inequality:$$k^k<n!$$
and taking the log of both sides gives $$k*log(k)<log(n!)$$
From here, Stirling's Approximation takes away the factorial and replaces it with $$k*log(k)<n*log(n)-n+O(log(n))$$
After playing around with this last inequality for a while, I still have not been able to make improvements on the original bounds.
How could I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your last inequality will improve the bound you have already set, since I feel the $2k$ one is much stronger (the one that comes from the stirling approximation is on the order of $e \cdot k$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have  $$k \log (k) = n (\log (n)-1) + \frac 12\log(2\pi n)\\
n=\frac {k \log(k)- \frac 12\log(2\pi n)}{\log(n)-1}$$
We can bound $n$ by removing the negative term in the numerator and reducing the denominator, so 
$$n\lt \frac {k\log(k)}{\log(k)-1}$$
This appears to be reasonably close as $k$ gets larger.  For $k=20$ it gives $n \approx 30$ where $26! \gt 20^{20}$ and for $k=50$ it gives $n \approx 67$ where $62! \gt 50^{50}$
You can get a better result by iterating to convergence.  Let $n_0$ be the result from above, then iterate 
$$n_{i+1}=\frac{k\log(k)-\frac 12 \log(2 \pi n_i)}{\log(n_i)-1}$$
and round up.  It looks like it works starting at $k=7$, though convergence is slow there.  Convergence speeds up as $k$ gets larger.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be n< since k<n?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Thanks

Comment: This is good, but how do you justify the equality at the beginning?

Comment: We are taking Stirling as exact.  It is not, but the rounding will cover it.  It is also accepting fractional values of $n$ for the factorial, so you can consider replacing $n!$ with $\Gamma(n+1)$.  The same approximation obtains

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078997/inverse-of-a-factorial/2079043#2079043), you will see the magnificent approximation proposed by @rohjohn  (an eminent user on this site) for the inverse of the factorial.

Applied to your case, this would write

$$n \sim e\exp\left(\operatorname{W}\left(\frac1{e}\log\left(\frac{k ^k}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)\right)\right)-\frac12$$ where appears Lambert function. For sure, you need to use $\lceil n\rceil$.

Applied to a few cases
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & n \\
 5 & 7 \\
 10 & 14 \\
 15 & 20 \\
 20 & 26 \\
 25 & 32 \\
 30 & 38 \\
 35 & 44 \\
 40 & 50 \\
 45 & 56 \\
 50 & 62 \\
 55 & 68 \\
 60 & 74 \\
 65 & 80 \\
 70 & 86 \\
 75 & 92 \\
 80 & 98 \\
 85 & 104 \\
 90 & 109 \\
 95 & 115 \\
 100 & 121
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is very close to a straight line.

Generating values up to $k=1000$, a linear regression $n=a+ b k$ gives with $R^2=0.999965$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 8.89874 & 0.27580 & \{8.35486,9.44263\} \\
 b & 1.13730 & 0.00048 & \{1.13636, 1.13823\}
\end{array}$$

Trying for $k=1000$ $(1000^{1000}=10^{3000})$, the regression would give $n=1146$ while the formula leads to $n=1143$. Checking
$$1142! = 6.58 \times 10^{2997} \qquad \qquad 1143! = 7.52 \times 10^{3000}$$