# Analytical solution of a recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

A recurrence relation defined as below where $c$ is a constant:

$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
    c, & \text{if $n=1$}\\\\
    f(n-1)\left(\frac{c}{n}\right), & \text{if $n>1$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$}
\end{cases}
$$

Further expanding the function we get:
$$
f(n) = \frac{c^n}{n!}\\\\
\delta(n) = f(n)-f(n-1) = \frac{c^n}{n!}\left(1-\frac{n}{c}\right),~n>1 ~\text{and}~ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+
$$

Ideally $\delta(n)\rightarrow 0 \text{ when $n\rightarrow\infty$}$. However, for computational purpose I am trying to solve $n$ when $\delta(n) = \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is a very small number. Offcourse $n$ can be found by calculating $\delta(n)$ for $n=2, 3, 4, \cdots$ until the value of $\delta(n)$ reaches $\varepsilon$.
In order to avoid all that, I am looking for an analytical solution to to solve $\delta(n) = \varepsilon$.

Comment: Consider $\,c=1.$ If $\,f(n)=\epsilon\,$ then  $\,1/\epsilon=n!\,$ so you are looking for the inverse of the factorial function.

Comment: I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078997/inverse-of-a-factorial) where they defined inverse factorial as: $n=\left\lceil e^{W\left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2 \pi    }}\right)}{e}\right)+1}-\frac{1}{2}\right\rceil$. What is $W$ here? Besides, it seems far more complicated to solve when $c\ne1$

Comment: The $\,W\,$ is Lambert $W$ function and the formula is only inverse of Stirling's approximation, and not the actual inverse of factorial.

Comment: As you wrote, the problem is difficult when $c\neq 1$. What I suppose is that, if you fix le value of $\epsilon$ to any value of you choice, using numerical analysis,we could find some *approximation*.

Comment: It would be much easier to solve, for $n$, $f(n)\leq \epsilon$ for any $c$ and $ \epsilon$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How can we solve $f(n) < \varepsilon$? Will it be correct to

Comment: This would be very simple. If this is of interest for you, just tell and I shall show tomorrow (it is almost curfew time here). Cheers :-)

Comment: I am not a mathematician, but never thought about inverse of factorial function so it is kind of new to me also what I have read so far inverse of factorial (also gamma function) is way more complicated compared to how simple gamma and factorial is. Offcourse I am interested @ClaudeLeibovici.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start looking at the problem of finding $n$ such that $f(n) \leq \epsilon$, it write
$$\frac {c^n}{n!}=\epsilon \implies n!=\frac {c^n}\epsilon$$ This has been solved in a [question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) where @robjohn proposed a superb approximation. Using your notations
$$\color{blue}{n\sim c \,e^{1+W(t)}-\frac 12}\qquad \text{where} \qquad \color{blue}{t=-\frac{\log \left(2 \pi  c \epsilon ^2\right)}{2 e c}}\tag 1$$ $W(t)$ being [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

For a first test, using $c=5$ and $\epsilon=10^{-15}$, this would give $n\sim 34.3499$ ( the exact solution being $34.3505$) then $\lceil n \rceil=35$. Checking
$$\frac {5^{34}}{34!}=1.97\times 10^{-15} >10^{-15}\qquad \text{while} \qquad\frac {5^{35}}{35!}=2.82\times 10^{-16} <10^{-15}$$

If you cannot access Lambert function, since $t$ is large, you can approximate it using the series expansion
$$W(t)\sim L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

For illustration, still for $c=5$ and $\epsilon=10^{-k}$, let us compute $\delta(n) = |f(n)-f(n-1)|$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & \log_{10}[\delta(n)] \\
 5 & -4.49533 \\
 6 & -5.45527 \\
 7 & -6.42008 \\
 8 & -7.38869 \\
 9 & -8.36033 \\
 10 & -9.33446 \\
 11 & -10.3107 \\
 12 & -11.2886 \\
 13 & -12.2681 \\
 14 & -13.2489 \\
 15 & -14.2308
\end{array}
\right)$$

It is the same order of magnitude. So, keep $(1)$ for the estimation.

If you really want to polish the root, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$g(n)=\log \left(\frac{c^n }{n!}\left(\frac{n}{c}-1\right)\right)-\log(\epsilon)$$ and perform some iterations of Newton method
$$n_{p+1}=n_p-\frac{g(n_p)}{g'(n_p)}$$ using for $n_0$ the value given by $(1)$ and
$$g'(n)=\frac{1}{n-c}+\log (c)-H_n+\gamma$$ For the first worked example, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 34.3499 \\
 1 & 35.2783 \\
 2 & 35.2718
\end{array}
\right)$$